# Android: different titles, same listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have 2 activities showing the same listview which is constructed though an adapter. My problem is that I want different titles in the ActionBar, I'm using AppCompat theme.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
(...)
}
```

How can I do the following command to set the title of the activity, if to do so I have to extends the Class from ActionBar and on MyAdapter class I have to extends BaseAdapter?

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"grey\">" + getString(R.string.app_name) + "</font>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood you correctly.
You have two activities with listview.
You create adapter MyAdapter for that listview.
You can create any design for actionbar in the activity.

```
public class GreyTitleActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grey);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"grey\">" + getString(R.string.app_name) + "</font>"));
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

}
```

sorry for my english

Comment: the activity where I construct the listview extends from BaseAdapter, so I can't do what you are suggesting since that is only possible if your activity extends from ActionBarActivity.

Comment: activity may extends from Activity, FragmentActivty or ActionBarActivity, but can't exendes from BaseAdapter. you need use Delegation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern